# How to convert a string to alphanumeric and convert spaces to dashes?

Tags: php

I'd like to take a string, strip it of all non-alphanumeric characters and convert all spaces into dashes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php/regex: "linkify" blog titles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244651/php-regex-linkify-blog-titles)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php/regex: "linkify" blog titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244651/php-regex-linkify-blog-titles)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use the following code whenever I want to convert headlines or other strings to URL slugs. It does everything you ask for by using RegEx to convert **any** string to alphanumeric characters and hyphens.

```
function generateSlugFrom($string)
{
    // Put any language specific filters here, 
    // like, for example, turning the Swedish letter "å" into "a"

    // Remove any character that is not alphanumeric, white-space, or a hyphen 
    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s\-]/i', '', $string);
    // Replace all spaces with hyphens
    $string = preg_replace('/\s/', '-', $string);
    // Replace multiple hyphens with a single hyphen
    $string = preg_replace('/\-\-+/', '-', $string);
    // Remove leading and trailing hyphens, and then lowercase the URL
    $string = strtolower(trim($string, '-'));

    return $string;
}
```

If you are going to use the code for generating URL slugs, then you might want to consider adding a little extra code to cut it after 80 characters or so.

```
if (strlen($string) > 80) {
    $string = substr($string, 0, 80);

    /**
     * If there is a hyphen reasonably close to the end of the slug,
     * cut the string right before the hyphen.
     */
    if (strpos(substr($string, -20), '-') !== false) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, '-'));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is excellent, thanks for sharing your code. Pretty much exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

Ah, I have used this before for blog posts (for the url).

Code:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/m", "", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/ /", "-", $string);
```

`$string` will contain the filtered text.  You can echo it or do whatever you want with it.

Comment: If you like this answer, please click the checkmark to the right of this post.

Comment: Shouldn't that second line be done first? Also, what exactly is the purpose of that "m" in the end of your first preg_replace statement? Thanks

Comment: Like Decoy mentioned, that 2nd line won't replace anything since any non-alphanumeric characters will already be replaced by the 1st line, which includes spaces.

Comment: @Josh I fixed that 17 minutes ago...

Comment: @blake305 I apologize. I must've quickly overlooked the space. Typically, I look for the shorthand whitespace character class, `\s`, in regex to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @Josh its fine.  Would you mind upvoting my comment if you were the one that downvoted it?  thanks :)

Comment: @Decoy m is for multiline. To search and replace in multiple lines if string is written in mulitiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace(array('/[^[:alnum:]]/', '/(\s+|\-{2,})/'), array('', '-'), $string);
```